# asp.net web page over vpn

Tags: asp.net

I published a web application to one of app servers.  Now, if I am connected within my company network (no login require), I can access the web site no problem.  Now, if I am connected from outside of the network over VPN, I can't access the website (Getting page not found appears).  Do I need to configure IIS on the app server for allowing the connection over VPN?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have your firewall/router configured correctly to allow traffic from external sources.  When your connected via VPN it is like you are connected to the internal network.  Without the VPN you need to make sure it is routed correctly and visible through your firewall.  Can you ping the IP that you are trying to get to?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get DNS resolution when you connect over the VPN?  If you are trying to hit an internal machine name address, you might try changing to the IP address of the machine.